# Changing the variable of a primary key column name in SQL with ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Please read before I get accused of copying and pasting code.

With some personal tweaking from an ajax tutorial, I got my wanted output working where It displays "YES", "NO", or "CANCELLED" on a column. Now I am trying to change my primary key name from "id" to "orderid" but my sql and my ajax stops functioning when I do so.

It may sound simple enough but I get confused because "id" is all over the place. **It is used as a variable in my ajax code, an attribute in html and the name of the primary key in my SQL table.**

I would like some help in knowing which "id" will I change in my code if I alter my primary key name in SQL from "id" to "orderid"?

- I only have two files: "connection.php" and "index.php".
- The table name is "user".

**index.php**

```
<?php
 include 'connection.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <table class="table">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Scheduled</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <?php
         $table  = mysqli_query($connection ,'SELECT * FROM user');
         while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ ?>
             <tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
               <td data-target="email"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>

               <td data-target="scheduled">
                 <input id='userId' type='hidden'/>
                 <?php
                   if ($row['scheduled'] == 1) {
                  ?>

                  <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">YES</a>

                 <?php
                   } else if ($row['scheduled'] == 0) {
                   ?>
                  <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">NO</a>
                 <?php
               } else if ($row['scheduled'] == 2) {
                   ?>
                  <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">CANCELLED</a>
                 <?php
                   }
                  ?>
               </td>
             </tr>
        <?php } ?>

   </tbody>
 </table>


</div>

   <!-- Modal -->
   <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">

       <!-- Modal content-->
       <div class="modal-content" style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="form-group">
             <a href="#" id="update_yes" class="btn btn-success text-center center-block">YES</a><br>
             <a href="#" id="update_no" class="btn btn-danger text-center center-block">NO</a><br>
             <a href="#" id="update_cancelled" class="btn btn-warning text-center center-block">CANCEL</a>
           </div>

         </div>
       </div>

     </div>
   </div>

</body>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

   //  append values in input fields
     $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){
           var id  = $(this).data('id');
           var scheduled  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text();

           $('#scheduled').val(scheduled);
           $('#userId').val(id);
           $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
     });

     // now create event to get data from fields and update in database

     $('#update_no').click(function(){
        var id  = $('#userId').val();
        var scheduled = 0;

        $.ajax({
            url      : 'connection.php',
            method   : 'post',
            data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
            success  : function(response){
                          // now update user record in table
                           $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text('<a href="#">NO</a>');
                           $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                           window.location.reload()
                       }
        });
     });

     $('#update_yes').click(function(){
        var id  = $('#userId').val();
        var scheduled = 1;

        $.ajax({
            url      : 'connection.php',
            method   : 'post',
            data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
            success  : function(response){
                          // now update user record in table
                           $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').html('<a href="#">YES</a>');
                           $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                           window.location.reload()
                       }
        });
     });

     $('#update_cancelled').click(function(){
        var id  = $('#userId').val();
        var scheduled = 2;

        $.ajax({
            url      : 'connection.php',
            method   : 'post',
            data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
            success  : function(response){
                          // now update user record in table
                           $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text('<a href="#">CANCELLED</a>');
                           $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                           window.location.reload()
                       }
        });
     });

});
</script>
</html>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$connection =   mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' ,'' ,'ajax_test');

if(isset($_POST['id'])){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $scheduled = $_POST['scheduled'];

    $result  = mysqli_query($connection , "UPDATE user SET scheduled = '$scheduled' WHERE id='$id'");
}
?>
```

**database name "ajax_test", table name "user"**

- the change that I mentioned is here, from "id" to "orderid".

[image: user]

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: I am aware of that but I am still practicing ajax. I will concern myself on SQL injections after I solve problems like this.

Comment: If you rename `id` to `orderid` in your `user`-table, then you need to change the references for that column: `WHERE orderid = ...` and use `$row['orderid']` instead of `$row['id']`.

Comment: my bad, edited the question. the database name is ajax_test and the table name being used is user.

Comment: tried changing the "WHERE", "$row['id']", and "data" in "$.ajax({" to orderid, but the update stopped working.

Comment: I never said that you should change anything in your ajax-request. You should _only_ change the keys that's _directly_ referencing the database column. So change it _only_ in your query and when you're trying to access the value from the database: `$row['orderid']`.

Comment: Alright I got it working now, Thank you very much. in my ajax-request, i was referring to this: "data : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},". I assume now that the id in the data refers to the id used in the variable in ajax.